# How to add space between the images being fetched using database through php

Tags: php, html, css

I am using following code to fetch images using database with php.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  //To excute result query 

{

echo "<a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'><img src=\"" . $PathImage .       $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a>XX;

}
```

Here I am using $row[logo] is fetching the path of images stored on the server and  XX to put the spaced between the images having the same color of text XX as background, and  but I want to use the proper method I know this can be done using table but I want to do it without using table.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: you want to put space in place of XX??

Comment: What has this to do with PHP or MySQL? More a HTML/CSS question

Comment: Sorry, I thought I am using php and mysql so I tagged like that. I will take care from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo "<a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank' style='margin:10px'><img src=\"" . $PathImage .       $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a>XX;
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like:

```
echo <a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank' style='margin:10px'>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

write like

```
echo $row[logo]." ";
```

or

```
echo "<a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'><img src=\"" . $PathImage .       $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

space by css

```
 echo "<a style='margin-right:10px;' href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'><img src=\"" . $PathImage .       $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a>";
```

Comment: Using &nbsp worked but I still think its not the right way, managing it through css would be better. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your code is broken anyway, you've forgotten to close the quotes! Something like this would work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  //To excute result query 
{

echo "<a href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'><img src=\"" . $PathImage . $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a> ";

}
```

But I'd go with a CSS solution and add a margin to the image instead:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  //To excute result query 
{

echo "<a style=\"margin-right:10px;\" href='http://".$row['website']."' target='_blank'><img src=\"" . $PathImage . $row['logo'] . "\" height = $FooterWidth /></a>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put

```
echo "<img src='" . $row[logo] . "' style='margin: 10px;'>";
```

using CSS. I would strongly recommend reading into CSS, as it is a basic thing in all web development! You could start at http://www.w3schools.com/css/.

Good luck!